# Docker Networking and VLANs

Tags: docker

I have a question regarding docker networking over (host) VLAN interfaces.

I tried to ssh out of a docker container to a server over a VLAN network, but the connection could not be established (time-out).

### Setting:

I have two machines (lets call them server and laptop) connected by

- A network using vlan (lets call it "private")
- A "normal" network (lets call it "public")

I tried to connect from a container on the laptop to the server via SSH, using the *private* network

### Diagnostics steps:

- A "native" SSH connection works fine, using both the *private* and the *public* network.
- An SSH connection from within the container on the laptop to the server using the *public* network is possible.
- wireshark (listening on the laptops vlan interface) told me that a [SRV] package was sent, and the server responded with a [SRV, ACK]. However, the container seems to not have received this, which led to a [SRV, ACK] re-transmission of the server AND also to new [SRV] packages from the container.
- I started a `nginx` container listening on `0.0.0.0` (on all interfaces) - it was reachable from the *public* network, but not from the *private* network
- I installed `nginx` natively on the laptop, again listening on all interfaces. It was reachable over both networks, *private* and *public*.

So the problem seems to be related to "docker and vLANs": wireshark moreover suggests that "outgoing" is possible, but "incoming" not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Outgoing connections from default containers are NATed. Does your wireshark trace show a source address of the public network for the vlan packets?  Is that public address routable on the "private" network?

Answer (score 3):

At the moment the best option to do that is using the (currently) experimental feature "[Ipvlan Network](https://github.com/daftano/docker/blob/master/experimental/vlan-networks.md)".

> The Linux implementations are extremely lightweight because rather
>   than using the traditional Linux bridge for isolation, they are simply
>   associated to a Linux Ethernet interface or sub-interface to enforce
>   separation between networks and connectivity to the physical network.

The [documentation](https://github.com/daftano/docker/blob/master/experimental/vlan-networks.md) is quite large and can't be copied here, however, once installed the experimental version, to create the ipvlan network and run a container attaching to it you should run:

> #### Ipvlan
>
> ```
> docker network  create -d ipvlan \
>   --subnet=192.168.1.0/24 \ 
>   --gateway=192.168.1.1 \
>   -o ipvlan_mode=l2 \
>   -o parent=eth0 db_net
> ```
>
> #### Start a container on the db_net network
>
> ```
> docker  run --net=db_net -it --rm alpine /bin/sh
> ```

On that page there is much more to read.

Few notes:

1. `-o ipvlan_mode=` defaults to L2 mode if not specified
2. The containers **cannot** ping the underlying host interfaces as they are intentionally filtered by Linux for additional isolation.
3. Experimental means it's considered not ready for production and could have some bugs. The documentation states that it's "provided for test and evaluation in your sandbox environments."

Comment: The documentation and Docker changed a lot in the last 4 years. The most important bits of that documentation are in the answer. The new documentation is at https://docs.docker.com/network/macvlan/